# How to find the event type from the swt.SelectionListener?

Tags: java, events, swt, ccombo

I have a scenario like in a CCombo box if we select the list option using UP and Down arrow keys then it should select the value and still in editing mode for confirmation until we click enter(This is acceptable for user).
Where if we select the list option using mouse click immediately it should confirm the vale without asking enter key.

Both the key and mouse click notifies the swt.SelectionListener.
In this SelectionListener I need to find weather the selection is made from key or mouse click.
So trying to find the type from this SelectionEvent after widget selected, but unfortunately "type" is not available.

Could anyone help me out in this to find the type? OR any other way to find the event type?

Comment: Looking at the source code I don't think there is any straightforward way to distinguish these events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an workaround for this issue
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=230398